# Monotone priority queues

Tags: data-structures, priority-queues, queues, abstract-data-types

I'm a little confused about how monotone priority queues work.

As far as I understand:

- A **queue** is a FIFO data structure
- A **priority queue** is a queue where the current element of highest (or lowest) priority is served before an item of lower (or higher) priority

Now, for monotone queues, I read [the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Specialized_heaps) on Wikipedia (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_priority_queue)):

> Monotone **priority** queues are specialized queues that are optimized for
>   the case where *no item is ever inserted that has a lower priority* (in
>   the case of min-heap) than any item previously extracted.

I'm a little confused here. Does this mean that a **monotone priority queue** is nothing else than a regular **priority queue** with an **`enqueue`** method that simply **prevents** anyone from adding elements that are *lower* (monotone increasing) or higher (monotone decreasing) than the min (or max) element that was previously extracted?

If so, in what ways are these FIFO queues "optimized" for monotonicity?

Comment: "... than any item previously *extracted*", not "inserted" -- so the input sequence is not required to be monotonic.

Comment: Thanks @j_random_hacker good call. I updated the OP accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but with that cleared up, I don't see how your second link fails to explain things. A data structure can come with arbitrary assumptions about the inputs it accepts; a particular implementation may choose to check those and throw an error when they are violated, or not (e.g. if checking is considered too expensive). I think the bucket queue example on the monotone PQ page is a nice example: The exact same data structure has different time complexities depending only on *the assumptions made about* its input.

Comment: To give a similar example: Insertion sort takes $O(n^2)$ time, but insertion sort on nearly-sorted inputs, in which each element is displaced at most $k$ positions from its final destination, is just $O(kn)$. Some other sorts do not have this property (e.g., heapsort). So it could be said that insertion sort is optimised for nearly-sorted inputs.